# Display / Load HTML Body only on Results of a Function

Tags: javascript, html

I am building an application using HTML, Javascript, CSS. When the user opens the app a function will check if the user is already registered. If registered then display the welcome screen with some message. If not registered then show a button to register. Now I have tried many things but the HTML page (body) shows the welcome message and also the Registration button when the app is opened.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   function checkuser(){
   //check if user already regsitered
   if yes{ display(welcome) : block}
  else {display(register) : none}
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body onload="checkuser()">
<div id="register">
<button>Register User</button>
</div>
<div id="welcome">
 <p>Welcome</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is happening is on opening the app (before / after registration), both the **div** are displayed and *then after the check* the page *re-loads and shows correct **div***. I want that the page should hold itself from displaying anything till the check is finished and the function should control which **div** to display.
Any idea what should be done?
Thanks.

Comment: You should do this sort of check server side

Comment: How do you check if the user is already registered ?

Comment: @DavidJones - yes the check is done at server end just that based on the response of the server the div / body needs to be displayed.

Comment: @Max - When the app opens it contacts the backend server (coding is done in html) and checks if a particular ID exists....this ID is generated (and stored in the server) when the user does a login / register to the app for the first time.

Comment: Why the need for the javascript though? You should perform the check on the server first of all and redirect them depending on their logged in status

Comment: Loading icon is displayed till the results are populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading icon is displayed till the results are populated.